# Model rendering mess up other renderings

Tags: directx, rendering

This is kinda noobish question, but still:

I created a simple terrain map (rectangle planes with ground texture, which I render with 'DrawPrimitive()') and they work perfectly.  than, I rendered a static model (with no frame hierarchy) and the terrain turned to be messed up!

Once the model is rendered, all the terrains vertices comes out concentrated in the corner of the model, somewhere near the axises zero point.

the model looks ok, so I don't think there's a problem with it.

I assume there's just something needs to be cleaned up after rendering the model, but I don't know what!

I tried clearing all the transformations (by setting my world matrix to identity matrix) but it's still messed up!

any ideas?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you maybe provide some code, typically the render loop and HLSL technique file if you are using one? And how did you create the model, and possibly the setup code for importing the model, and creating the rectangle planes might also help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try using PIX from DirectX SDK -> Utilities. It will show you all calls and how the vertices were transformed as they go out of vertex shader. It's very helpful for such things!

Answer (score 0):

"Normally" in directx you have a world, view and projection matrix; and the world matrix would need to be set for each separate object you draw.